# What are these HTML <c- g> tags? Undefined custom element?

Tags: html, css, custom-element

When looking at the source code of the HTML standard there were some tags that I didn't recognise..

For example in this snippet:

```html
    <pre><code class='idl'>[<c- g>Exposed</c->=<c- n>Window</c->]
<c- b>interface</c-> <dfn id='htmlparagraphelement' data-dfn-type='interface'><c- g>HTMLParagraphElement</c-></dfn> : <a id='the-p-element:htmlelement' href='dom.html#htmlelement'><c- n>HTMLElement</c-></a> {
  [<a id='the-p-element:htmlconstructor' href='dom.html#htmlconstructor'><c- g>HTMLConstructor</c-></a>] <c- g>constructor</c->();

  // <a href='obsolete.html#HTMLParagraphElement-partial'>also has obsolete members</a>
};</code></pre>
```

From https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html

I thought these may be custom elements, but it doesn't look like they are defined via the custom element registry.. This is the result of interrogating the `customElements` object.

```js
>>> customElements.get('c')
undefined
>>> customElements.get('c-')
undefined
```

Is this allowed? (I'd guess so since it's from the HTML *standard*, but it's still surprising to me). How would the browser know how these elements are supposed to be displayed? For example `display: block` vs. `display: inline`.

Comment: You can get the full list of the `c-` elements with `document.getElementsByTagName("c-")`. Also, the element `c-` isn't defined anywhere in the HTML Standard or MDN. I even looked in the [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) and [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) of MDN

Comment: All elements take the initial, or inherited for inherited properties, value of each CSS property until specified otherwise. So they would be `display:inline` It seems the `<c->` elements are used for syntax highlighting within the IDL blocks.

Comment: It seems that they are kind of custom elements but not defined as custom elements. I don't think you need to worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are custom-elements (and valid HTML), generated by  [bikeshed](https://github.com/tabatkins/bikeshed/tree/main/bikeshed)'s [highlighter](https://github.com/tabatkins/highlighter/).

There is no need to define these as customElements because they don't bring any particular behavior, all they do is to ... save bandwidth.

Here is [the commit](https://github.com/tabatkins/highlighter/commit/75e91017fa33302a9a02876c8a2e4e8d138bf975) excerpt:

> #### TERRIBLE-HACK-ALERT  Switch to using <c- kt> instead of <span clas…
>
> …s='kt'> to cut the weight of highlighting in half. Still valid HTML!

So apparently by switching from `<span class="kt">` to `<c- kt>` (and `span.kt {` to `c-[kt]{`) they saved half of the weight induced by their highlighting.

Though as they say, it's a "terrible-hack", which still can make sense when building a tool that generates the majority of Web Standards pages, which can get very lengthy.

---

Regarding the default display of such custom-element, I'll quote [Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750093/what-are-these-html-c-g-tags-undefined-custom-element/68750667#comment121501417_68750093) which did put it nicely:

> All elements take the initial, or inherited for inherited properties, value of each CSS property until specified otherwise. So they would be `display:inline`

---

And regarding your expectation to see only best practices in the specs sources, it's better not assume so. Read the content of these pages, don't look at how they're built.
Most HTML editors don't look at the tools that will generate the pages, they write the specs in a pseudo-HTML language full of templates.
Or as it's put in the [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whatwg/html/main/source):

> ```html
> <!-- Note: This file is NOT HTML, it's a proprietary language that is then post-processed into HTML. -->
> ```